# Attempt to read property "id" on bool (View: D:\website\Image\resources\views\layout.blade.php), variable not transfering to view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I keep encountering this error on Laravel 8 with PHP 8. Im grabbing the id from the view like so:

`<li><a href="category/{{$catego->id}}">{{$catego->categories}}</a></li>`

This then goes to web.php like so:

`Route::get('category/{id}', [UserController::class, 'categories']);`

It then goes to the categories function like so:

```
 function index(){ 

$category = category::all();

    return view('index', )->with('category',$category);


    }
    
function categories($id){
    if(category::where('id',$id)->exists())
    { 
  $category = category::where('id', $id)->first();
$viewimage = image::where('categories_id', $category->id)->get();
    
return view('categories',compact('category','viewimage'));
    }
    else {
        return view('index')->with('status','category not exist');
    }
}
```

It gives me correct information when i debug;

`dd($viewimage)`

But on categories page it give me error.

```
@extends('layout')

@section('categories')
<section class="main-section">
            <div class="main-container">
            <div class="img-main-container">
                 
           <div class="img-container">
            @forelse($viewimage as $catimg)
            <img src="{{asset('upload/images/'.$catimg->image)}}" alt="">
           </div>
           <p>{{$catimg->name}}</p>

           @empty
           <p>data not found</p>
           @endforelse
         </div>
      

            </div>
        </section>
@endsection
```

Here is layout page data I fetched category at two place, one is in header and second is in the form

Header category fetched here

```
 @foreach($category as $catego)
                    <li><a href="category/{{$catego->id ?? 'not found'}}">{{$catego->categories ?? 'not found'}}</a></li>
```

@endforeach

category in form fetched here

```
   @foreach($category as $catego)
                                <option value="{{$catego->id ?? 'not found'}}">{{$catego->categories ?? 'not found'}}</option>

                                @endforeach
```

**When i use @umarFayyaz way i got the data how i want, but categories in the header lost showing "not found"**

**Uploaded full controller above **

Comment: Interesting, I have a feeling that you have multiple records with the same id in the category table. Also you can view model bind categories for that request and use dependency injection to get a model if it exists.

Comment: try this {{$catimg->name ?? 'not found'}}

Comment: @UmerFayyaz Didn't work

Comment: @amac I have a table named 'images' where i have multiple record of same category id. First i got all the categories in the index page. but when i click on the category, it gives the error.

Comment: Well the error is on your layout @zeenatmalik. Could you share that view? If not at least more of the controller. Secondly, if you are doing some logic on the Layout view and looping over things that may cause this issue to arise. Or you are loading the authed user not the queried user and using the same variable name.

Comment: @amac check it now please

Comment: `$category = category::where('id', $id)->first();`, then `foreach($category as $catego)` is not doing what you think it's doing. `->first()` returns a single `Category` model, or `null`. `foreach()` on a single Model instance loops it's public properties, so `$catego` is a `boolean` and `true/false->id` is not valid. Just remove your foreach and do `$category->id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to edit your question, but there was too much detail that I didn't want to override the original question. Perhaps take a look at this formatting and some of the benefits of laravel to simplify and possibly fix the problem.

Below try and label the file in which you are describing. Use StudlyCaps or better known as PascalCasing for class names. Variables should be in camelCasing. Typically database tables are plural when it relates to a single model ('users', 'categories). When in a pivot snake casing again without pluralization and in alphabetical order (ie category_user) and column names are in snake_casing (ie a post made by a user... 'posts' table and 'user_id' column on posts... 'posts.user_id'). The main reason I state these is because laravel does a lot under the hood to attempt to handle relationships, methods, etc... based on naming conventions. when you have a belongsTo relationship you will see when properly named something like.

Device.php:

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function author(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }


    // $this->author_name 
    public getAuthorNameAttribute($value)
    {
       return ucfirst($value) 
    }

}
```

category.blade.php:

```php-template
<li>
    <a href="category/{{ $catego->id }}">
        {{ $catego->categories }}
    </a>
</li>
```

Here you can reach for route model binding or route explicit binding. Also I think you should and want to separate this into two separate controller. UserController should know stuff about users and CategoryController should know stuff about categories... S.O.L.I.D principles where you are most likely coupling and violate Single Responsibility, Open/Closed, Interface Segragation, and Dependency Inversion which means with interface implementations and using abstractions instead of concrete classes setup in this way would also violate Liskov.

```php
use Http/Controllers/CategoryController;


/* don't shorten variable names just be more specific or location based within your repository. This way when doing a search on your code base the location or use case is intuitive and easily found.*/

Route::get('category/{category}', [CategoryController::class, 'detail']);
```

with the binding you can then achieve something like this

CategoryController.php

```php
function detail(Category $category, Request $request) {
    
    if(is_empty($category)) { 
        return view('index')->with('status','category not exist');
    }
    
    $categoryImages = image::where('categories_id', $category->id)->get();
    
    return view('categories', compact('category', 'categoryImages'));
}
```

UserController.php

```php
//again here naming doesn't make sense doing an all on an index but returning back to the view in singular form.
function index(Request $request) { 
    $category = category::all();

    return view('index', )->with('category',$category);
}
    
function categories($id){
    if(category::where('id',$id)->exists()) { 
        $category = category::where('id', $id)->first();
        $viewimage = image::where('categories_id', $category->id)->get();
    
        return view('categories',compact('category','viewimage'));
    }

    return view('index')->with('status','category not exist');

    // this really should be reversed to save on queiries there are also other ways
    if(!category::where('id',$id)->exists()) { 
        return view('index')->with('status','category not exist');
    }
    
    $category = category::where('id', $id)->first();
    $viewimage = image::where('categories_id', $category->id)->get();
    
    return view('categories',compact('category','viewimage'));
    
}
```

Comment: There is way more but I saw that you were getting your answers and didn't want to waste my time. '

Comment: There's a few issues with this answer. 1) `href="category/{{ $catego->id }}"` is not how your do links in Laravel. Use `{{ route('category.show', $category) }}` (if using a proper Resource Controller), or `{{ url("categories/{$category->id}") }}` as an alternative. 2) `detail(Category $category, Request $request)` is backwards; the `Request $request` typically is "injected" first. 3) `image::where('categories_id', $category->id)` - use a Relationship, `$category->images`. 4) `if(category::where('id',$id)->exists())` then `category::where('id', $id)->first()` - Continued...

Comment: You correctly pointed out that's backwards, but you can also simply do `$category = Catgory::find($id); if (!$category) { ... }`; `::find($id)`, or `->where('id', $id)->first()` can return `null`, so `if(!$category){ ... }` is enough to check it. `::findOrFail()` is also available.

Comment: Definitely, @TimLewis, I was updating this while working. I am glad you added to it. Please don't think of me as terrible for not catching :). I believe you are incorrect on show though, I believe it is meant not to share collections or arrays of data. Hence, the term details. Also backwards is true in a logical sense when conforming to laravel best practices unwritten rules. However, because the container resolves these injected dependencies order doesn't matter, just to be clear. I think you have a point on number 3 however, I still don't know if we know the OPs true intentions there.

Comment: Last point, I get you point but I also think there are simplified versions even than that. However, my point was not to right the most optimized etc... but definitely good stuff and hopefully OP takes time to read!

Comment: *"Please don't think of me as terrible for not catching"* - Haha, never! We all overlook things, or have differing opinions on what is "correct", subject to best practices and whatnot. Uniformity and consistency is key, which is why I recommend `Request $request` coming first, as it would for non-POST routes (since it would be the only injection). Point 3 is for using Laravel to it's fullest, i.e. not having to manually query the `images` Model/Table like that when a relationship will do. And yeah, it can be optimized more, this is just the code-reviewer in me pointing things out. Cheers!

Comment: Also you're correct; for viewing multiple `$categories`, the correct route would indeed be `route('categories.index')`; `categories.show` would be for a single `$category`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller (`GET | /photos/{photo} | show | photos.show`). `href="categories/{$category->id}"` will work, but if you change the route in `routes/web.php` (add a prefix, etc.), then you'd have to manually update it. `route()` handles that automatically, `url()` would have the same issue, so I always recommend using `route()` and `->name('example')` 

Comment: For sure @TimLewis, ya awesome stuff. I haven't actually developed that deeply in laravel lately and was looking at some of the new features. That and php are really starting to really reshape php to a bright promising future. Enjoy have a good weekend!

Answer (score 1):

in the categories function, $category is a instance so you can't use foreach on it.
Instead of `<li><a href="category/{{$catego->id}}">{{$catego->categories}}</a></li>`, try this `<li><a href="{{ url('category',$category->id')}}">{{$category->categories}}</a></li>` if you want to get an instance of category.

Comment: Sorry, I mis spoke and this is why I wanted to post an answer just on the formatting and naming. As well as some easy to reach for laravel functionality because this is very confusing. Not due to the actual question but the code naming itself.

Comment: Property [categories] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\website\Image\resources\views\layout.blade.php)

Comment: You have more than one $category being injected as a variable. Combined with naming conventions one is a level to deep and one is a level not deep enough.

Answer (score -1):

Here i came up with a solution.

I removed the category fetching query from Controller and fetched categories from layout page.

I didn't understand why it worked. Helpful If someone can explain.

```
  <ul>
                    <li><input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Search category" class="search-field"></li>
                   @php
                   $category = App\Models\category::all();
                   @endphp

                    @foreach($category as $categ)

                    <li><a href="{{url('category/'.$categ->id)}}">{{$categ->categories}}</a></li>
```

@endforeach

Comment: *"fetched categories from layout page."* - That very much violates the MVC architecture; data fetching should never be done in the views. Also, `$category` is a bad variable name for `::all()`, since that returns a Collection of 0 or more records. `$categories` is more appropriate, and would let you do `@foreach($categories as $category)`

Comment: Ya the naming really needs work. If you were able to get the categories from the layout then just use the same object from the logic above. You are just doing all()...

Comment: @amac Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate you and you debugging skills. Yah am really bad in naming variables, As i am new to laravel. Thanks again.

Comment: Ya no worries @zeenatmalik, its not meant as a dig. there are a ton of conventions in the framework that you are probably unaware of. Which is what I was bantering back and forth with Tim about. Also, in this kind of forum Q&A we are given the specific scopes pertaining to the problem and subjects with in that. We don't know the scope of your project. Which is where and why you may and could have totally legitimate reasons for naming schemes and conventions. Just one piece of advice to give is know that when posting to something like SO we only have the knowledge that is shared in the Question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).